# How to get MultipartFile java 1.42

Tags: java, file-upload, multipart, apache-commons-httpclient, java1.4

I am using xslt for client-side and java 1.42 for server -side and no framework such as Spring.My xslt code is:

```
<form method="post" id="frmFillFile" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br></br></input>
                        <input type="hidden" name="readFile" value="readFile"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>
                        <input type="file" accept="text/plain, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" ID="fileSelect"     /> 
                    </form>
```

For server  side i need MultipartFile.The code should be something like that:

```
MultipartFile mFile= rProxy.getRequest().getMultipart("file");
```

But java 1.4 doesn't support get MultipartFile from httpServletRequest.

Do you have any suggestion for get file?

Comment: apache commons upload http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/

Comment: @Tom, i culdn't see server side code example for java 1.42

Comment: hmmm.  there are old versions available that predate java 1.5  can't help more than that I'm afraid.